# Can't boot fresh install of Xubuntu 22.04 on Elitebook 2170p

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu

I am failing to boot a fresh install of Xubuntu 22.04 on an HP Elitebook 2170p.

I can boot from USB stick, repartition the HD and install. However the machine won't boot into the freshly installed Linux:
`BootDevice not found`

I tried a full install, cleaning the hard drive and different variants of partitioning. Do I need EFI? I tried with and without.

Before the installation I had a Dual Boot running on the machine with some kind of old Windows install and Xubuntu 20.04 next to it, working fine for years.

I am happy to provide more information, if needed. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is booting now, the problem is solved. The solution was to activate the UEFI Native Mode and use an EFI partitioning scheme.

Using the boot-repair tool helped a lot:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

If anyone is interested in this, I enabled the "UEFI Native Mode" and used the following partitioning scheme:

```
/dev/sda1; FS: grub2 core.img;Mount point:-;Size:1 MB; Flags: bios_grub
/dev/sda2; FS: fat32; Mount point:/boot/efi;Size:513 MB; Flags:boot, esp
/dev/sda3; FS: ext4; Mount point:/;Size:25 GB
/dev/sda3; FS: ext4; Mount point:/home;Size:95 GB
```